# How to stop PHP from echoing blank tags

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP code calling data from a MySQL table. However, when it displays the data, I get a blank `<p>` tag on every alternate row, like this:

```
 <p>Row1</p>   <p></p>   <p>Row 2</p> <p></p> <p>Row3</p>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])){

     $user=$_GET{'user'};

     $sql="SELECT DISTINCT `user` FROM `users` WHERE user='$user'";

     $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         echo "<p>$row[0]<p/>";
     }
}
```

Any ideas on what might cause this?

PS: I added a line to the function saying `echo "sql;"` and it came out with something like this

> `SELECT DISTINCT`user`FROM`user`WHERE user='John'`

When I run this directly on the database without PHP code, it work fine without blank entries. So it's not a database problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Below I have pasted two while loops. The first one is the one above with the main question that is not working,
and the second one, I copy pasted from another file, and edited it for accordingly for this particular code.

However, the first while loop prints out double paragraph tags, while the second one doesn't. I tried copy pasting the loops individually into a different document, and the result is the same, loop one gives double tags, while loop two prints single tags (as it should). But still, I can't see the difference between the two loops.

```
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<p> $row[0]<p/>";
}

/*while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<p> $row[0]</p>";  
}*/
```

Essentially, I have a solution to my problem, but I don't see why it works

Comment: I think you have to use if condition in while loop for data isset / empty or not. if not empty then print.

Comment: may be difference of  echo "<p>$row[0]<p/>"; and  echo "<p> $row[0] <p/>"; notice the space there. but I am not sure. also let me know the reason if you got .. :)

Comment: that `<p/>` is not how you close a tag... THAT is: `</p>`

Answer (score 1):

Please Try the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET['user'])){

     $user=$_GET{'user'};

     $sql="SELECT DISTINCT `user` FROM `users` WHERE user='$user' AND user <> '' ";

     $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           if(!empty($row[0]))
           {
             echo "<p>$row[0]<p/>";
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but to no avail! :( This again proves my initial hypothesis that it's a php problem, not an empty entry in the database.

Comment: just edit the query and use not empty condition in mysql query

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to this,To exclude blank column value

```
$sql="SELECT DISTINCT `user` FROM `users` WHERE user='$user' AND user <> ''";
```